# Force flex item's text content to wrap to fill the height of the item even when there's enough width to stretch

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML:

```
 <style>
      .f-container {
          display: flex;
      }

      .f-item {
          border: 1px solid lightgray;
          height: 40px;
          word-break: break-all;
      }
</style>

<div class="f-container">
  <div class="f-item">some long content here that stretches very long</div>
</div>
```

which renders to this:

```
_________________________________________________
|some long content here that stretches very long|
|                                               |
|_______________________________________________|
```

I need the text inside the flex item to wrap so that the width of the item is smaller:

```
_________________________
|some long content here  |
|that stretches very long|
|________________________|
```

Any way to do this with flex item? Or maybe I don't need flexbox and can use something else?

Comment: Why don't you set the width of the container like `width: 25%` or even in `px` ? That will allow the text to wrap otherwise if the width is not set it'll just expand.

Comment: You.... might be able to do this with CSS grid? or maybe `flex-direction:column;` Though that's a really really weird design. Most designs care much more about **width** than about **height**, because **width** is a limited resource (max-width:100%), whereas **height** can be unlimited. (Depending on what kind of design you have, you might be happier doing `min-height:2.5em;width:33%;` or something. Even though I know that `min-height` isn't even close to what you asked for, it might be closer to the designer's original intention.)

Comment: @EliezerBerlin, it's for auto-resize functionality in the grid columns

Comment: Oh. Yeah, that's not a `min-height` situation.....Yikes. If you're doing a table, though, then why do you care about the height? Why not just do `.f-item{flex: 1 1 0;}` or `.f-item{flex:1 1 25%;}`?(Just define the width, and let flexbox automatically adjust the the height to the size of the tallest element.) I think most flex-tables are built like that.

Comment: ....You essentially want `height:40px;width:auto;`, right? That's.... not going to work even slightly. They aren't *going* to be columns if each row has a different amount of elements and each element has a different width (due to `width:auto`), because the width depends on the content. (If the first item on row #1 has width 25%, and the first item on row #2 has a width of 20%, and the first item on row #3 has a width of 30%, because they fill their height first and then afterwards has `width:auto`, then the whole thing is going to look awful.

Comment: `height:40px;width:auto;` will end up looking something like this: https://imgur.com/tCJjlc4 . I'm not sure it's what your designer was going for. (Like I said earlier, I suspect what you actually want is to give it a fixed width. Something like this: `height:40px; flex:1 1 0;`.)

Comment: there will only be one row required for calculations of auto-resize of columns, it's not a design